# Async task made my application crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

First of all i have seen two problems 
 [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871642/error-with-doinbackground-method)
[second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616123/asynctask-doinbackgroundstring-clashes-with-doinbackgroundparams)

but they are different , 
i use `Async task` to communicate with server side and it works fine except two situations 
first one if the server stopped for any reason that caused crashes in my application 
second situation is when i am connected to network but there is no internet on this access point 
**My Question is** how can i handle this error to avoid crashes ?
this is my **code**

```
    public class news_tab extends Fragment{
    ListView newsLIST;
    String result_news,result_fav;
    String [] Hot_news,newsName1,newsText1 ,agentName;
    int [] Hot_news_id,agent_id;
    int []  fav_id;
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<String> newsName,newsText,agentNamelist;
    public news_tab()
    {

    }
    public news_tab (Context context)
    {

        this.context=context;
        newsName=new ArrayList<String>();
        newsText=new ArrayList<String>();
        agentNamelist=new ArrayList<String>();
    }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, container, false);
            rootView.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/back"));
            newsLIST=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsLV);
            getFavouriteNews();
            news();


            return rootView;
        }
public void getFavouriteNews() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
                        HttpRequestSender http = new HttpRequestSender((Activity) context);
                        result_fav = http.SEND_POST_get_news_fav("**********/dal/login.asmx/getdata_newsfav");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result_fav="";
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Check the internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    //  result = http.SEND_Check("******/Login?email="
                    //      +username.getText().toString()+"&password="+password1.getText().toString());

                    Log.d("String", result_fav);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {



                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

                if(result_fav.contains("text_news")) {

                    //   x.cancel();
                   // Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome Favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // JSONObject jb = null;
                    try {
                        JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result_fav);
                        ArrayList <String> newsName , newsText,agentNamelist,urlList;

                        fav_id= new int [JA.length()];


                        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);

                            fav_id[i]= (int)   JO.get("news_id");


                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                   // Toast.makeText(context,"No News",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            }
        }.execute();

    }
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
```

and finally i got this **error**

```
03-29 10:15:45.500 24585-24585/com.Offferly.ahmad.hakimi E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.Offferly.ahmad.hakimi, PID: 24585
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.Offferly.ahmad.hakimi.tab.news_tab$2.onPostExecute(news_tab.java:217)
   at com.Offferly.ahmad.hakimi.tab.news_tab$2.onPostExecute(news_tab.java:179)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 10:15:45.540 2952-20003/? E/WakeLock: release without a matched acquire!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: As I see your code You have written a toast inside doInBackground().Remove Toast as doInBackground() runs on different Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if the server stopped for any reason that caused you are getting null response in your **result_fav** variable.. You need to handle null in onPostExecute() method 
   like this

   if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(result_fav)){

   // your code

   }else{

   // Show toast Null Response

   }
2. **In second situation** :

Remove Toast message in doInBackground() method .can not show toast msg in doInBackground() method

You can try this in your getFavouriteNews() method :

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
  //then call your async task                      
}

else
{
  //Show Toast no internet                      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot show Toast inside doInBackground() Method. If you want to do this use below code.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       Toast.makeText(<your class name>.this, "Cool Ha?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}});
```

Try this.

Comment: @AhmadSabbagh - Explain your full problem, I am happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` condition from

```
if(result_fav.contains("text_news"))
```

to

```
 if(!TextUtil(result_fav) && result_fav.contains("text_news"))
```

Answer (score 0):

remove toast from doinbackground. you should run it on ui thread.code like below

```
     @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
          try {
          if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
       HttpRequestSender http = new HttpRequestSender((Activity) context);
result_fav = http.SEND_POST_get_news_fav("**********/dal/login.asmx/getdata_newsfav");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result_fav="";


      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              Toast.makeText(context,"Check the internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }});
                        }
                        //  result = http.SEND_Check("******/Login?email="
                        //      +username.getText().toString()+"&password="+password1.getText().toString());

                        Log.d("String", result_fav);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the AsyncTask in `onViewCreated`, not in `onCreateView`.

Comment: can you explain ?

Comment: It is possible that your AsyncTask requires a view that is in your `news.xml` layout file. When you put AsyncTask execution in `onViewCreated`, it might require the view that is not yet created, throwing NullPointerException. Therefore you can try to run the AsyncTask in `onViewCreated`